# Reactjs error when importing react-bootstrap

Tags: react-router, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I have `Login.js` and this is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';
class Login extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="middle-box text-center loginscreen animated fadeInDown">
            <div>
                <h1 className="logo-name">Pz</h1>                    
            </div>
            <form>
                <FormGroup bsSize="large">
                    <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Large text" />
                </FormGroup>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Login
```

This is my routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Main from '../components/layouts/Main';
import Blank from '../components/layouts/Blank';

import LoginView from '../views/Login';
import MainView from '../views/Main';
import MinorView from '../views/Minor';

import { Route, Router, IndexRedirect, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

export default (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <IndexRedirect to="/main" />
            <Route path="main" component={MainView}> </Route>
            <Route path="minor" component={MinorView}> </Route>
            <Route path="login" component={LoginView}> </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>

);
```

The error is :

**warning.js:45 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Login`.**

**invariant.js:39 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Login`.**

Whats wrong with the code? please help

Answer (score 0):

Yeaaaahh, i know what the problem, need the latest version of react-bootstrap.
in my case, i've used v0.30.5